# Add link in a video or a gif

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, gif

Do you know any solution to click an element in an animated media, eg gif or video?

Example in the attached link how I can open a link when I click (at any time) on the running guy.
[link](https://media.giphy.com/media/l2Sqc3POpzkj5r8SQ/giphy.gif)

Comment: You add an `a` tag around it?

Comment: If you use the developers tools in your browser to inspect the gif in the sample link you provided you will see that it is not just a gif. If you want a link inside a video like the ones that come at the end of a youtube video those are part of the video object, not HTML markup, but either flash or HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the Freezeframe.js library.

Demo: https://ctrl-freaks.github.io/freezeframe.js/
Github: https://github.com/ctrl-freaks/freezeframe.js/

At the hover event the gif stops and there are links with a static position on each clickable element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript by putting a click function on the containing element:

```js
document.getElementById("media-holder").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "https://google.com";
};
```

```css
#media-holder {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="media-holder">
  <img src="https://i.giphy.com/media/l2Sqc3POpzkj5r8SQ/giphy.webp" />
</div>
```

Or you can wrap the element in an anchor tag:

```html
<a href="https://google.com">
      <img src="https://i.giphy.com/media/l2Sqc3POpzkj5r8SQ/giphy.webp" />
</a>
```

Comment: But with an a tag, i can click everywhere, I need to click only on a men, no on full gif.

Comment: @Delta why would you want to do that? That sounds like a bad user experience to me.

Comment: I know but I need it